# Facebook style show user birthday using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a facebook style user birtyday function using php. But i have a problem i am not getting any results with my code. What i am doing wrong here anyone can help me?

[image]

```
        <?php 
        public function UserBirthDay($uid,$base_url) {
             $uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db,$uid);
             $query=mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT uid,fullname,birth_day,birth_month,username 
FROM users WHERE 
    MONTH(birth_month) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birth_day) = DAY(NOW());") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
             $data = array();
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                 $data[]=$row;
              }
              if(!empty($data)) {
                // Store the result into array
                 return $data;
              } 
        ?>
```

and

```
<?php 
 $birthDay=$DaySo->UserBirthDay($uid,$base_url);

 foreach($birthDay as $data) {
    $birthUserFullname=$data['fullname'];
    $dbusername = $data['username'];
    $bd = $data['birth_day'];
        if (date('m-d', strtotime($bd)) == date('m-d')) {
       echo '<div class="birthdayUser">
    <div class="birthdayuser">
      <div class="birthday_icon"></div>
      <div class="birthdayUName"><a href="#">'.$birthUserFullname.'</a></div>
    </div>
   </div> ';
        }

 }

?>
```

Comment: do a var_dump of $birthday

Comment: also you do not have username value in your query

Comment: @Akin sorry i have added. There are not have any problem

Comment: what does the $birthday array have? is it empty?

Comment: If you're using singular values (like `04` and `07`) then you shouldn't need to us the `MONTH()` and `DAY()` MySQL functions in your query.

Comment: @thebluefox But i have already used `MONTH()` and `DAY()` please look at the question. `MONTH(birth_month) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birth_day) = DAY(NOW())`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: @DevStud - Read my comment again. I said you **shouldn't** need to use those functions.

Comment: This would be trivial if you had a `DATE` type column with all the values in one place. Organizing it in different columns just makes your life way more difficult, there's nothing to gain by it.

Comment: Let me be clearer. You should be comparing like so; `birth_month = MONTH(NOW()) AND birth_day = DAY(NOW())`. You don't need to wrap the columns in the `MONTH()`/`DAY()` functions. Like @tadman says - this would be easier if you were storing the dates correctly.

Comment: @thebluefox I get a result now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is with your select statement. You're wrapping the columns in your comparison in `MONTH()` / `DAY()` functions when you don't need to.

```
SELECT uid,fullname,birth_day,birth_month,username 
FROM users 
WHERE MONTH(birth_month) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(birth_day) = DAY(NOW())
```

Your column `birth_month` contains a 2 digit representation of the month. `MONTH(NOW())` will return a 2 digit representation of the month. Therefore, you don't need to wrap your column in the `MONTH()` MySQL method. Same goes for the `birth_day` comparison.

```
SELECT uid,fullname,birth_day,birth_month,username 
FROM users 
WHERE birth_month = MONTH(NOW()) AND birth_day = DAY(NOW())
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments by Tadman;

> WARNING: When using mysqli you should be using [parameterized](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

I repeat this advice here because it's something many will urge you to listen to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and attantion i fixed the SQL injection problems. So i don't understand why someone gives me - vote :)

Answer (score 1):

You have issue in your php condition

try below code

```
 foreach($birthDay as $data) {
    $birthUserFullname=$data['fullname'];
    $dbusername = $data['username'];
    $bd = $data['birth_month']."-".$data['birth_day']; //concate month and day
        if ($bd == date('m-d')) {
       echo '<div class="birthdayUser">
    <div class="birthdayuser">
      <div class="birthday_icon"></div>
      <div class="birthdayUName"><a href="#">'.$birthUserFullname.'</a></div>
    </div>
   </div> ';
        }

 }
```